# Can a site mailbox sync with an Outlook 2010 client (O365)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site-mailboxes

We're using O365 for SharePoint and Outlook, however some users still make use of the Outlook 2010 desktop client.

From my experience, the site mailbox auto-syncs on the site owner's machine in the Outlook 2013 client, but I noticed it didn't in Outlook 2010.

**May I ask if a SharePoint site mailbox is able to sync with an Outlook 2010 client connected to O365?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Microsoft guidance on using site mailboxes in Office 365:

- **Outlook 2013 that ships in Office 365 ProPlus or Office Professional Plus is required.**
- **No other version of Outlook allows you to use a site mailbox as described here.**

Documentation here: https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Prepare-for-using-site-mailboxes-in-Office-365-6381daa5-3d98-4629-972d-d19e1dc48c1b?CorrelationId=7f5fd7c7-4662-49b4-8366-55ff0be70d54&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US